# Use Symfony TestContainer inan environment not called "test"

Tags: symfony, codeception

I write a unit test in CodeCception, my config `Unit.suite.yml`

```yaml
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - Asserts
      - Symfony:
          environment: 'autotest'
step_decorators: ~
```

I have a separate environment for running Unit test in pipeline - `autotest`, and I would like to use my services via `Codeception\Module\Symfony->grabService`, but I get the error that the service should be public, however, if I use the test environment, Symfony loads `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\TestContainer` and there are no errors, is there any way to get Symfony to load this container for the `autotest` environment?

I tried to make all services public in `config/packages/services.yml` via

```yaml
when@autotest:
  services:
    _defaults:
      public: true
      autowire: true
      autoconfigure: true
```

I also tried adding each separate service and putting `public: true` on it, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `framework.test` to `true` in your custom environment.

E.g.

```yaml
#framework.yaml

when@test:
  framework:
    test: true
    csrf_protection: false
    session:
      storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file


when@autotest:
  framework:
    test: true
    csrf_protection: false
    session:
      storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

I think this *might* do the trick. Hopefully there aren't other sites where the "test" environment is "assumed" to be literally "test".